# Typescript couldn't find custom 3rd party types from package

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have written an NPM Package in Typescript which you can find here: https://github.com/DiceBear/avatars

The package includes own declarations (which are automatically generated with the option "compilerOptions.declaration") and declarations for 3rd party packages.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./lib",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "declaration": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types",
            "typings"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/"
    ]
}
```

In the "package.json" I have an option "types" for the path of the generated declarations.

```
{
  "name": "@dicebear/avatars",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "main": "lib/index",
  "types": "lib/index"
}
```

But if I install the package in a final project, Typescript ignores  the declarations for the 3rd party packages under "typings".

How can I handle the generated declarations with my own declarations for the 3rd party packages?

Comment: Please create an [MVE: Minimal, complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and insert the code directly into your post. Thx.

Comment: Try specify as "lib/index.d.ts".

Comment: @SherylHohman edited.

Comment: @unional Same result. Typescript finds the generated typings, but not the own additional typings.

Comment: `typings` you mean typings you installed using `typings` and installed to the `typings` folder?  You need to use "include" in `tsconfig.json` to include them. Not `typeRoots`

Comment: @unional Thanks for your patience. The problem does not exist if I run tsc directly in the repository.

The problem only exists if I use the package in another repository. I install the first repository with npm. Then I import the package. Typescript finds the generated declarations, but not the self-created ones.

Comment: I'm converting a project I created to TypeScript and it uses Avatars, the library you wrote. I think I'm running into the problem you are describing here and it's still present. Is this correct?

Comment: @FlorianKörner can you provide an example of a final project, so we can reproduce the problem "But if I install the package in a final project, Typescript ignores the declarations for the 3rd party packages under "typings". In my test setup, I can happily consume your library, so I suppose this error occurs in some advanced use-cases?

Comment: I could solve the problem with the following lines in the library.
https://github.com/DiceBear/avatars/blob/v4/packages/avatars/src/types.ts#L1-L3

@pupeno I would be happy to help you with your problem.  How can I reproduce your problem? Which version do you use (typescript, avatars, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Your main project it's a monorepo, I suggest you to use [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).

For each package:

1. cd packages/*package_name*
2. npm link

than in root `package.json` file make sure `@dicebear/avatars` appears only once (not both in `dependencies` and `devDependecies` as now).

Change `dependencies` from *file* to *version*: `"@dicebear/avatars": "4.2.0",` instead of `"@dicebear/avatars": "file:packages/avatars",` (this for all the *dependencies*).

Last, in the roor folder, for each dependency

3. npm link *package_name*

(I mean `npm link @dicebear/avatars`, `npm link @dicebear/avatars-avataaars-sprites`, and so on...)

Issue `npm install` once again and it should be enough.

Hope this helps.